# Exact the same regular expressions in Java match in one code but not in another

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a crawler in java to crawl a specific website. In this code I used regular expressions to match some specific urls, but they don't(fig1)! I try the url and the regular expression in another class staticaly(fig2), and it works! I'm so confused, and don't understand what is going on.

Thanks,

```
public static void crawl()throws IOException, InterruptedException{
    HttpResponse httpResponse;
    String seed = "http://www.5040.ir/";
    String Html = "";
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParametersGenerate());
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(seed);
    visitedUrls.add(seed);
    try {
        httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            Html = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
            Document doc = Jsoup.parse(Html, "www.5040.ir");
            Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("http://www\\.5040.ir/[^/]*\\.html");
            Matcher matcher;
            for (Element e : links) {
                matcher = pattern.matcher(e.absUrl("href"));
                if (matcher.matches()) {
                    if (visitedProductURls.contains(e.absUrl("href")))
                        continue;
                    else {
                        getProductLinksQueue().add(e.absUrl("href"));
                        visitedProductURls.add(e.absUrl("href"));
                        System.out.println(e.absUrl("href"));
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (!e.absUrl("href").equals("")) {
                        if (visitedUrls.contains(e.absUrl("href"))) {
                            continue;
                        } else {
                            getCrawlUrls().add(e.absUrl("href"));
                            visitedUrls.add(e.absUrl("href"));
  //                    System.out.println(e.absUrl("href"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (httpGet != null) {
            httpGet.releaseConnection();
        }
    }
    while(true) {
        if (!getCrawlUrls().isEmpty()) {
            httpGet = new HttpGet(getCrawlUrls().getFirst());
//                System.out.println(getCrawlUrls().getFirst());
            getCrawlUrls().removeFirst();
            try {
                httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                    Html = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
                    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(Html, "www.5040.ir");
                    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("http://www\\.5040.ir/[^/]*\\.html");
                    Matcher matcher;
                    for (Element e : links) {
                        matcher = pattern.matcher(e.absUrl("href"));
                        String tata = e.absUrl("href");
                        if (matcher.matches()) {
//                    System.out.println(e.absUrl("href"));
                            if (visitedProductURls.contains(e.absUrl("href"))) {
                                continue;
                            } else {
                                getProductLinksQueue().add(e.absUrl("href"));
                                visitedProductURls.add(e.absUrl("href"));
                                System.out.println(e.absUrl("href"));
                            }
                        } else {
                            if(!e.absUrl("href").equals("")) {
                                if (visitedUrls.contains(e.absUrl("href"))) {
                                    continue;
                                } else {
                                    getCrawlUrls().add(e.absUrl("href"));
                                    visitedUrls.add(e.absUrl("href"));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (httpGet != null) {
                    httpGet.releaseConnection();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**fig1**

```
public static void main(){
String regex = "http://www\\.5040\\.ir/[^/]*\\.html";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    String test = "http://www.5040.ir/test.html";
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
    if (matcher.matches())
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    else
        System.out.println("not matched");

}
```

**fig2**

Comment: The regexes you use in fig1 and fig2 are completely different and in fig1 I cannot find the URL you use to be matched by the regex. Could you simply show the used regexes and URLs which match / do not match .

Comment: excuse me tomse, I edit it. in the fig1 the link will be a link from the urls in the seed page(here seed = www.5040.ir), and in fig 2 is the value of one of these links (test = "http://www.5040.ir/test.html"). in fig 1 this is not matched but in fig 2 does!

Comment: Have you tried to debug your fig1 or just add a `System.out.println` with the value returned by `e.absUrl("href")` to see if this is exactly the same URL as in fig2?

Comment: yes, they are the same. I have checked that with the debugger which is embedded in IntelliJidea.

Comment: Could you please add the URL which does not match, because if everything is excactly the same it _has_ to match, but maybe your program logic has a bug somewhere? Btw. your regex patterns are not exactly the same, just search for the first one in your IDE the second will not be found, but the difference is just fig1: "." and fig2: "\\.", so this should not be the problem since fig1 matches for more cases than fig2. To ensure they are exactly the same put your regex in a static variable to be accessed from both.

Comment: The Url that is not matched, is `http://www.5040.ir/max-saver-GAS-Lowering-domestic-fuel.html`. I fixed the regular expressions in fig1, but it still does not work!

Comment: I tried your URL and it matches (`System.out.println(Pattern.compile("http://www\\.5040.ir/[^/]*\\.html").matcher("http://www.5040.ir/max-saver-GAS-Lowering-domestic-fuel.html").matches());`). Note: if there would be spaces before or behind your URL your regex would not match. So maybe that's the problem - if not you should debug your code or reduce the implementation to isolate the part which does not work...

Comment: Tahnk you @tomse. It solved. the problem was that in my main code(not the code here) I was reading the regex string from a file and in this process every "\" was converted to "\\". My problem was that the intellij idea 14 debugger tool, does not show me this conversion! So when I modified my regex into `http://www\.5040\.ir/[^/]*\.html`, it worked. thanks for your guidance.